# Check if an equation is linear for a specific set of variables

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a scrip that automatically generates equations.

The equations are constructed using sympy symbols.

I would like to know whether or not these is a way to check if the equations are linear in terms of certain variables.

eg.

```
a, b, c, d = sympy.symbols('a, b, c, d')

eq1 = c*b*a + b*a + a + c*d
```

check for the following: is `eq1` linear in terms of `a`, `d`?

```
True
```

Comment: How complex can the expressions be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is (jointly) linear in a given set of variables if all second-order derivatives are identically zero (including mixed ones). This can be checked as follows:

```
def is_linear(expr, vars):
    for x in vars:
        for y in vars:
            try: 
                if not sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(expr, x, y), 0):
                    return False
            except TypeError:
                return False
    return True
```

In the loop, every derivative is taken and checked for equality to zero. If sympy cannot decide if it's zero (raising TypeError) then it's not identically zero.

Output:

```
>>> is_linear(eq1, [a,d])
True
>>> is_linear(eq1, [a,c])
False
```

---

To check for separate linearity (e.g., separately in a and separately in b),  drop mixed partial derivatives:

```
def is_separately_linear(expr, vars):
    for x in vars:
        try: 
            if not sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(expr, x, x), 0):
                return False
        except TypeError:
            return False
    return True
```

Output:

```
>>> is_separately_linear(eq1, [a,d])
True
>>> is_separately_linear(eq1, [a,c])
True
```

Comment: Just want to point out that sympy.Eq might not (and often doesn't) return zero even if an expression does equal zero. You have to use sp.simplify, and even then there is no guarantee that sympy is able to determine that the expression is zero.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way would be to check the degree of the expression as a polynomial in each variable.

```
In [17]: eq1 = c*b*a + b*a + a + c*d

In [18]: degree(eq1, a)
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: degree(eq1, d)
Out[19]: 1
```

and expression is linear if the polynomial degree is <= 1.

If you know the expression is a polynomial in your variables, you can also just check for powers that contain the variable.

```
In [21]: [i for i in eq1.atoms(Pow) if i.base == a]
Out[21]: []

In [22]: eq2 = b*a**2 + d + c

In [23]: [i for i in eq2.atoms(Pow) if i.base == a]
Out[23]:
⎡ 2⎤
⎣a ⎦
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from 404, if f<sub>xy</sub>=0, then f<sub>yx</sub>=0. Thus, the computation time can be cut in half for the mixed derivatives solution.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def is_linear(expr, variables):
    combs = combinations_with_replacement(variables, 2)
    try:
        return all(sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(expr, *t), 0) for t in combs)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```